# Kubenetes Mongo Deployment Loses Data After Pod Restart

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod, persistent-volumes

Recently, the managed pod in my mongo deployment onto GKE was automatically deleted and a new one was created in its place. As a result, all my db data was lost.

I specified a PV for the deployment and the PVC was bound too, and I used the standard storage class (google persistent disk). The Persistent Volume Claim had not been deleted either.

Here's an image of the result from `kubectl get pv`:
[pvc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emsMe.png)

My mongo deployment along with the persistent volume claim and service deployment were all created by using kubernets' `kompose` tool from a docker-compose.yml for a [prisma 1 + mongodb](https://v1.prisma.io/docs/1.34/prisma-server/local-prisma-setup-je3i/) deployment.

Here are my yamls:

`mongo-deployment.yaml`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose -f docker-compose.yml convert
    kompose.version: 1.21.0 (992df58d8)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: mongo
  name: mongo
  namespace: dbmode
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: mongo
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: kompose -f docker-compose.yml convert
        kompose.version: 1.21.0 (992df58d8)
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: mongo
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: prisma
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
          value: prisma
        image: mongo:3.6
        imagePullPolicy: ""
        name: mongo
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
        resources: {}
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/mongo
          name: mongo
      restartPolicy: Always
      serviceAccountName: ""
      volumes:
      - name: mongo
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mongo
status: {}
```

`mongo-persistentvolumeclaim.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: mongo
  name: mongo
  namespace: dbmode
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Mi
status: {}
```

`mongo-service.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose -f docker-compose.yml convert
    kompose.version: 1.21.0 (992df58d8)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: mongo
  name: mongo
  namespace: dbmode
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "27017"
    port: 27017
    targetPort: 27017
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: mongo
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

I've tried checking the contents mounted in `/var/lib/mongo` and all I got was an empty `lost+found/` folder, and I've tried to search the Google Persistent Disks but there was nothing in the root directory and I didn't know where else to look.

I guess that for some reason the mongo deployment is not pulling from the persistent volume for the old data when it starts a new pod, which is extremely perplexing.

I also have another kubernetes project where the same thing happened, except that the old pod still showed but had an `evicted` status.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I've tried checking the contents mounted in /var/lib/mongo and all I
> got was an empty lost+found/ folder,

OK, but have you checked it was actually saving data there, before the `Pod` restart and data loss ? I guess it was never saving any data in that directory.

I checked the image you used by running a simple `Pod`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: my-pod
    image: mongo:3.6
```

When you connect to it by running:

```
kubectl exec -ti my-pod -- /bin/bash
```

and check the default mongo configuration file:

```
root@my-pod:/var/lib# cat /etc/mongod.conf.orig
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb # 
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:
```

you can see among other things that `dbPath` is actually set to `/var/lib/mongodb` and **NOT** to `/var/lib/mongo`.

So chances are that your mongo wasn't actually saving any data to your `PV` i.e. to `/var/lib/mongo` directory, where it was mounted, but to `/var/lib/mongodb` as stated in its configuration file.

You should be able to check it easily by `kubectl exec` to your running mongo pod:

```
kubectl exec -ti <mongo-pod-name> -- /bin/bash
```

and verify where the data is saved.

If you didn't overwrite in any way the original config file (e.g. by providing a `ConfigMap`), `mongo` should save its data to `/var/lib/mongodb` and this directory, not being a mount point for your volume, is part of a `Pod` filesystem and its ephemeral.

#### Update:

The above mentioned `/etc/mongod.conf.orig` is only a template so it doesn't reflect the actual configuration that has been applied.

If you run:

```
kubectl logs your-mongo-pod
```

it will show where the data directory is located:

```
$ kubectl logs my-pod 
2020-12-16T22:20:47.472+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=my-pod
2020-12-16T22:20:47.473+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.6.21
...
```

As we can see, data is saved in `/data/db`:

```
dbpath=/data/db
```

Comment: Thanks! I suspected that the data was not actually saving to the PV. However, I did not find /var/lib/mongodb in my running pod, and even after I changed the mongo deployment yaml to point to /var/lib/mongodb for the mountPath, the directory still only contained the lost+found/ folder. I also checked the logs destination for mongodb and there wasn't anything there

Comment: I completely forgot that my mongodb data was saving into the /data/db folder. Thanks for your response, I finally made the connection that my persistent volume needed to be mounted at that directory. Works now!